# how to stop/cancel dowloading file?

Tags: android

how can stop / cancel a file while downloading?
im using urlconnection and inputstream.
code is worked but i cant cancel dowloding with it.
my code for download :

```
            int count;
            try {
                URL url = new URL(f_url[0]);
                URLConnection conection = url.openConnection();
                conection.connect();
                int lenghtOfFile = conection.getContentLength();
                InputStream input = new                  BufferedInputStream(url.openStream(),8192);
                File myDir = getDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_MUSIC,
                        Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                Intent i = getIntent();
                String name = i.getStringExtra("name");
                File mypath = new File(myDir, name + ".mp3");
                mypath.createNewFile();
                mypath.mkdirs();
                OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(mypath);
                byte data[] = new byte[1024];
                long total = 0;
                while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
                    total += count;
                    publishProgress("" + (int) ((total * 100) / lenghtOfFile));
                    output.write(data, 0, count);
                }

                output.flush();

                output.close();
                input.close();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
            }

            return null;
        }
```

Comment: Try making URLConnection connection object global.
And call conection.close();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tthe general idea is to use a flag (which can be set from an external thread) that is checked periodically:

```
while (!cancelled && shouldDoStuff) { doStuff(); }
```

Using a flag allows the code to run to normal completion (well, sorta), distinguish between different "exceptions", and perform the appropriate cleanup operations as it deems fit.

Now, *an [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) already provides an appropriate cancel mechanism* through a flag that can be checked:

> **Cancelling a [AsyncTask] task:** A task can be cancelled at any time by invoking `cancel(boolean)`. Invoking this method will cause subsequent calls to `isCancelled()` to return true. .. To ensure that a task is cancelled as quickly as possible, you should always check the return value of `isCancelled()` periodically ..

And trimmed snippet from the above-linked documentation:

```
for (..) {                  // Keep going until done ..
  publishProgress(..);
  if (isCancelled()) break; // .. or until flagged.
}
```

(Using AsyncTask takes care of the icky details, like correct implementation of said flag which should be `volatile` at the very least.)